# Visual Studio 2013 TableAdapter Config Wizard for Oracle

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2012

I'm a new user to setting up a query using the TableAdapter Config Wizard. I'm trying to run a simple query, and I thought it should look like this:

```
select id, name, val
from tableA
where name = @parm1 and val = @parm2
```

This does not work. How do I write the query and pass parameters using Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, your parameters need to be prefixed with a colon, not an at sign:

```
select id, name, val
from tableA
where name = :parm1 and val = :parm2
```

On a related note, when you instantiate the parameters, unlike Sybase/SQL Server, you actually leave the identifier off of the parameter name:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("parm1", OracleDataType.Varchar));
```

I may have the Data Type enum slightly off, but you get the idea.